# Splicing array nested within ng-repeat,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repeat

The array is structured like so

```
  $scope.structure = {
    sections: [{
      id:0,
      sectionItems: []
    },{
      id:1,
      sectionItems: []
    },{
      id:2,
      sectionItems: []
    }]
};
```

I have a nested ng-repeat so I can show items within sectionItems[]
(Inside should be objects and one of the keys is Name - not relevant)

```
<div ng-repeat="sections in structure.sections" class="col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <ul class="screenW-section">
        <li class="col-xs-6" ng-repeat="item in sections.sectionItems" 
         ng-click="item.splice($index, 1)">
            {{item.Name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> </div>
```

I want to be able to remove items on click but the 
**ng-click="item.splice($index, 1)**
Is not working no matter how I format it.

Comment: All of your stuff works, problem was in another part of a code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.structure = {
    sections: [{
      id:0,
      sectionItems: ['1','2','3']
    },{
      id:1,
      sectionItems: ['11','21','32']
    },{
      id:2,
      sectionItems: ['12','22','32']
    }]
};
  
  
  $scope.remove = function(sectionItems,index){
     sectionItems.splice(index, 1);     
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="sections in structure.sections" class="col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <ul class="screenW-section">
        <li class="col-xs-6" ng-repeat="item in sections.sectionItems" 
         ng-click="remove(sections.sectionItems,$index)">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove an item you need to remove it from the array.
So, for example, you could do

```
ng-click="remove(sections.sectionItems, $index)"
```

in the view, and

```
$scope.remove = function(array, index) { 
  array.splice(index, 1);     
}
```

in the controller...

Comment: "sections" and "sectionItems" are arrays and cannot be referenced that way.

Comment: Since it's nested you would need the index of both the section and the sectionItem. In other words, you need a reference to the correct section also in your answer.

Comment: @CountGradsky: *you* are using it as objects in the view you show... Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcoS maybe you ment $scope.structure.sections[n].sectionItems.splice(index, 1);

Answer (score 1):

You're calling splice on the item and not the array

```
ng-click="sections.sectionItems.splice($index, 1)"
```

Comment: I am getting "TypeError: scope.$eval(...).splice is not a function" on every solution